# Send or receive file or data over sockets simultanously

Tags: c#, sockets

My server sends out ping every 10 secs and disconnects client if it elapses 20 secs without a reply

If I am going to be sending out a really large file to the client from server or vice versa, the send() or receive() methods might block long enough that the client immediately times out after sending is finished.

Also when the sending method is running, I can not use other threads to send other data over the same socket or I might corrupt the stream and file I am sending (or can I without corrupting the file?)

Should I just make the client make another socket and connect over to a different port to my server to do long sending/receiving operations?

Edit: Here's how for example, the server sends out a message

```
    public void SendTo(System.Net.EndPoint toclient, byte[] data)
    { 
    foreach(ClientData client in clientlist)
    {
        if(client.s.RemoteEndPoint == toclient)
        {
            lock(client.sendlock)
            {
                int size = data.Length;
                byte[] sizebytes = new byte[4];
                sizebytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(size);
                client.s.Send(sizebytes);
                client.s.Send(data);
            }
        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: Show us the code you use to handle the sockets.

Comment: The server uses .Net 4.0 async BeginReceive() and sync blocking send()
while client uses blocking send() and blocking receive()

Both my client and server a hundred lines of code at least I am not sure which part would be relevant

Comment: Btw both the client and server prefix the size of the message as an int in the first 4 bytes before the bytes of the message and sends them over. The receiver has to keep reading till end of number of bytes of messages is read.

Comment: As an aside, you may need your ping messages to come in that frequently for your own purposes, but TCP can go for much longer without dropping the connection. In the past, I've often used a ping interval of 10 _minutes_.

Comment: and why are you pinging tcp connections. you will know if the remote machine goes away

Comment: @pm100: You can know, but only when you try to do something with the socket (send/receive). Pinging is certainly useful when you want to show activity statuses and the like.

Comment: Well aside of pinging server, I want the client to be responsive while the transfer is going; I might want for example to send the client a message to stop and kill sending process.

Also, does TCP has a built in timeout procedures? How would I know if my client terminates unexpectedly?

Comment: Hi, We also tried same socket send/receive data but, getting some issues, can you update the complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these situations you should really have a dedicated ping port and another one for data transfers.

Certainly, you need to maintain two open connections per client but as far as I can see, one connection has a shorter lifespan while the other (for ping) lasts as long as the client wants (or can) to be connected.

About your code, you can refactor it a bit for clarity if not for anything else:

```
var client = clients.FirstOrDefault(c => c.s.RemoteEndPoint == toclient);
if(client != null) 
{
     lock(client.sendlock)
     {
        int size = data.Length;
        byte[] sizebytes = new byte[4];
        sizebytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(size);
        client.s.Send(sizebytes);
        client.s.Send(data);
     }
}
```